# Updating a column with random values between specific range?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column where I need to update it's value by random numbers between 1 and 3150 (just being specific)

Can I do this with a simple TSQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RAND()`, re-seeding the function on each call.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = 1 + FLOOR(3150 * RAND(CONVERT(varbinary, NEWID())))
WHERE ...
```

Comment: CHECKSUM(NEWID()) could be used too to seed RAND